# Itchy cat biting fur

Tags: cats, skin-condition, veterinarian

Recently my 12 year old domestic short haired cat has been biting/mowing her fur around her primordial pouch. She is neutered and only goes outside on our deck. I would get her to a vet, but the COVID-19 situation in my state (New York) is preventing me from doing so.

She is not taking any preventive flea medication, as she rarely ventures from our home.

What could I do on my own to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help], especially [How to ask good questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a general discussion forum, but a Q&A site. Your post currently contains only statements, but no real question. Are you looking for a home remedy or a way to get your cat treated by a vet despide the Covid pandemic? Please [edit] your post and add as much information as you can: Are there hairless or red spots of skin? Is your cat treated for fleas preventively? Did you bathe your cat recently?

Comment: If possible, i’d want to treat her with a home remedy, obviously if that’s not possible I’ll take her to a vet

Comment: Apart from the skin condition, the claws of your cat are much too long. In this relaxed pose you shouldn't see the claws at all. Please make sure your cat has an appropriate scratching post and if you end up taking her to the vet, ask them to shorten the claws.